# Driver for ATI Radeon Mobility M6 LY

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I'm looking for a driver for and old laptop running Windows 7 (32-bit).  It is a Compaq Evo N600c, which I believe has an ATI Radeon Mobility M6 LY video card in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=316675&prodSeriesId=316673&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1093#11314) from HP/Compaq's [site](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=316675&prodSeriesId=316673&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1093#11360)